# How to write an Axios get request with a query?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, axios

I am using the MERN-Stack (React, NodeJS, React, Express, + MongoDB). I want to write a get-request with Axios to call up a route in the backend. But I only want to retrieve specific data from my database. For that I want to use a query.
My URL looks something like this:
'http://localhost:5000/users?name=john'
So I only get users whose name is John.
I wrote an axios-request, which looks like this:

```
axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/user/getown", { params: { username: this.state.username } })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I am not sure if I pass the query correctly.
In the backend I am using Express and Mongoose to get the date from my MongoDB. Therefore I am using this code:

```
router.route("/getown").get((req, res) => {
  User.find({ username: req.query.username })
    .then((user) => res.json(user))
    .catch((error) => res.status(404).json("Error: " + error));
});
```

When I test the '/getown' route with Insomnia everything works correctly, so I think the mistake is in the frontend.

Comment: What request is sent by the browser? Devtools network panel will show you

Comment: It's a get request. Or what do you mean?

Comment: What does your debug console say? And in network tab of console?

Comment: In your explanations your write `users` and in your code only `user` without the plurial.

Comment: In the network tap it doesn't show the parameters. It only show 'getown?username=' . Is this normal?